# Static libraries not linked in Link Binary with Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, cocoapods

I am using Cocoapods 0.36.0.beta.1

If I have a static library libssl.a in my spec, found at TestSpec/Libs and I include it as a vendored library, it doesn't seem to get linked in the target project

Here is my podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "TestSpec"
  s.version          = "0.0.1"
  s.summary          = "Test"
  s.homepage         = "https://www.google.com"
  s.author           = { "Ciprian Caba" => "1@2.com" }

  s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source           = { :git =>     "https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPodsTest.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.source_files = 'TestSpec/*.{h,c,m,swift}'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'TestSpecBundle' => ['TestSpec/*.png']
  }

  # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  s.frameworks = 'UIKit'
  s.vendored_libraries = 'TestSpec/Libs/libssl.a'
  s.libraries = 'ssl'
end
```

And here is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'TestApp' do

pod 'TestSpec', :path => '../TestSpec'

end
```

What happens in the target project is that the libssl.a file gets included, the path to the Libs folder gets added to the Search path but on the Build Phases tab there is no linking done with the a file. From what I understood this should happen because of the s.libraries = 'ssl'

After almost one day of struggling and testing, I can't understand what I'm doing wrong

I've also created a repo with a [test project](https://github.com/cipriancaba/cocoapods-static-lib)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the libraries will never be added to the Build Phases Tab but instead will add the following line to Other Linker Flags:

```
-l"ssl"
```

[image: Build Phases Tab]

This will actually make the .a file build along with the target and it never needs to reach the Build Phases Tab